# Navbar tabs full size and center in mobile devices only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can i center my navbar `<li>`'s and make them 100% in mobile devices only?

At the moment i use

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

because in desktop mode i want my navigation on the right side.

When i switch to mobile device it looks like this: [Picture with navbar](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140514/bzyngz39.jpg)

How can i change this to full-width li's, who are centered?

Thank you.

**Edit:** I'll post my solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.

I solved my problem with the following lines of code:

**html-file:** i just removed `pull-right` in the `<ul>`:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**css-file:** i implemented the `pull-right` for myself and reset in later:

```
#myTab 
{ 
    float:right;
}

@media (max-width:768px)
{
    #myTab 
    {
        float:none;
    }   
    #myTab li {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Now it looks like:

[Link to result](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140514/9yg8njl8.png) - As you see i removed the `text-align: center;` part, just because left align look better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with media queries, when its under a certain amount of pixels width, change its width.

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
    #myTab li { width:100%; float:none; }
}
```

---

Edit - also added float:none, as it seems to be floated right right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to override the `.nav>li` classes when the menu collapses for smaller widths...

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  .nav>li {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/nFls8QUKXJ

Comment: Now the links are centered, but they are still on the right side (see picture in my post).
How can i bring them back to the left side and make the links 100%?
`width: 100%;` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand "the links are centered, but they are still on the right side"? They're centered (so what do you mean by right side?)

Comment: I already have a solution now with your answers _(but can't post it because StackOverflow say that i have to wait)_: My problem was that i used `pull-right` on the `<ul>`-Element, but it's okay. I removed it and implement it by myself with `#myTab { float:right; }`. Then i reset it in a media-Query with `#myTab { float:none; }` and set the width to full-width with: `#myTab li { width:100%; }`. More later. Thank you for your answer! :-)